# Passing/Using Scalar variable in extended stored procedure-exec master..xp_cmdshell

Tags: sql-server, exec

I have to export data from the Student table as CSV without using the export wizard. The below script works fine if we hardcode the registration number, but when using the variable @registration_no it gives an error : *must declare scalar variable*. On printing the @cmd the registration_no is correctly replaced by 101. Seems @registration is out of the scope of the exec master..xp_cmdshell

```
 Begin
    Declare @registration_no as int
    set @registration_no = 101
    Declare @cmd as nvarchar(4000)
    set @cmd = 'sqlcmd -s, -W -Q "set nocount on; select * from [Student_Management].[dbo].[Student] where registration_no = @registration_no " | findstr /v /c:"-" /b > "d:\student.csv" '  
    exec master..xp_cmdshell @cmd
END
```

Comment: SQL isn't a scripting language, a variable in a literal string isn't going to be replaced by the value of the variable in the batch. `SELECT '@Variable'` doesn't return the value stored within the variable, it returns the **literal** string `'@Variable'`.

Comment: @larnu can you please provide a solution, I tried through stored procedure too, but couldn't succeed. I want to export the data of many tables to CSV and have to provide a parameter(like registration_no) to filter the data. But need a script for the same and can't use wizard

Comment: You need to embed the value contained in your variable inside the string you build. It's a simple as that. Something like set @cmd = '.... where registration_no = ' + cast(@registration_no as varchar(11)) + ...

Comment: @SMor
Still getting: Must declare the scalar variable "@ registration_no".
Changed the set command to :
set @ cmd = 'sqlcmd -s, -W -Q "set nocount on; select * from [Student_Management].[dbo].[Student] where registration_no = +cast(@registration_no as int)" | findstr /v /c:"-" /b > "d:\student.csv"' 

OR 
set @ cmd = 'sqlcmd -s, -W -Q "set nocount on; select * from [Student_Management].[dbo].[Student] where registration_no = +cast(@ registration_no as varchar(11))" | findstr /v /c:"-" /b > "d:\student.csv"'

Comment: @SMor Still getting: Must declare the scalar variable "@ registration_no".

Answer (score 0):

```
create procedure sp_CSV_Export
@regno int
as
Begin
Declare @registration_no int = @regno
declare @bcp varchar(8000)

set @bcp = 'sqlcmd -s, -W -Q "set nocount on; SELECT * FROM [Student_Management].[dbo].[Student] WHERE registration_no= '+ cast(@registration_no as nvarchar(10))+' " | findstr /v /c:"-" /b > "d:\student.csv"'    
EXEC master..xp_cmdshell @bcp
end
```

This worked!